# I want to implement a tree grid , with searching and pagination

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to implement a grid having tree structure and pagination functionality .Here is my code which i implemented.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<meta charset="utf-8">   
<title>Example of Employee Table with twitter bootstrap</title>   
<meta name="description" content="Creating a Employee table with Twitter Bootstrap. Learn with  example of a Employee Table with Twitter Bootstrap.">  
<link href="content/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
<link href="content/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="content/css/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="content/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="content/css/bootstrap-theme.css.map" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="content/css/bootstrap.css.map" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="content/css/jquery.treegrid.css">


<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.2/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">  </style>


<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body style="margin:20px auto">  

<div class="container">



<table id="myTable" class="table tree-2 table-bordered table-striped table-condensed">
            <tr class="treegrid-1">
                <td>Laxmi</td><td>Additional info</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="treegrid-2 treegrid-parent-1">
                <td>Node 1-1</td><td>Additional info</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="treegrid-3 treegrid-parent-1">
                <td>Node 1-2</td><td>Additional info</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="treegrid-4 treegrid-parent-3">
                <td>Node 1-2-1</td><td>Additional info</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="treegrid-5">
                <td>ashish</td><td>Additional info</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="treegrid-6 treegrid-parent-5">
                <td>Node 2-1</td><td>Additional info</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="treegrid-7 treegrid-parent-5">
                <td>Node 2-2</td><td>Additional info</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="treegrid-8 treegrid-parent-7">
                <td>Node 2-2-1</td><td>Additional info</td>
            </tr>        
   </table>

</div>
</body>

   <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="content/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript"   src="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.2/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#myTable').dataTable();
});
</script>


<script type="text/javascript" src="content/js/jquery.treegrid.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="content/js/jquery.treegrid.bootstrap3.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.tree').treegrid();
            $('.tree-2').treegrid({
                 expanderCollapsedClass: 'glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right ',
                 expanderExpandedClass: 'glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down '
            });

        });
    </script>
```

but it is not working the scripts written in last one for tree and other for datatable are coinciding  .here is the link from where i have written code for pagination and searching.i want to integrate both pagination and tree grid .Can somebody please clarify me that when two scripts overlap and why it happens.Link for grid of pagination and searching.

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/823490/Bootstrap-Table-With-Sorting-Searching-and-Paging

Link for tree grid.
http://maxazan.github.io/jquery-treegrid/

Comment: yes I also needed this grid,If any one has solution please help it out